# Jersey, Tomcat: The requested resource is not available error in InjelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

I am new to Jersey and trying to convert a project from Spring MVC into Jersey. With my current build however, all requests return a `resource not available` error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
    runtime('org.hsqldb:hsqldb')
    compileOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

My Jersey Config

```
    @Configuration
public class JersyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JersyConfig() {
        registerEndpoints();
        configureSwagger();
    }

    private void configureSwagger() {
        register(ApiListingResource.class);
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8090");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage(OwnerController.class.getPackage().getName());
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }

    private void registerEndpoints() {
        register(OwnerController.class);
    }

}


    @Api(value = "Owner controller", tags = {"Owner resource"})
public class OwnerController {

    private final ClinicService clinicService;

    @Autowired
    public OwnerController(ClinicService clinicService) {
        this.clinicService = clinicService;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{ownerId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "get owner by id", response = Owner.class)
    public Response getOwner(
            @ApiParam(name = "owner id", value = "owner id that must be fetched") @PathParam("ownerId") int id ) {
        Owner owner = clinicService.findOwnerById(id);
        return Response.status(200).entity(owner).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/owners")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "get all owners", response = Owner.class, responseContainer = "List")
    public Response getOwners() {
        List<Owner> owner = (List<Owner>) clinicService.findAllOwners();
        return Response.status(200).entity(owner).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should register your package which contains jersey resources using packages() method in JerseyConfig() constructor

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: OK, I will write this as answer. Please accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your package which contains jersey resources using packages() method in JerseryConfig() constructor -

```
public JersyConfig() {
    packages("PACKAGE_CONTAINING_JERSEY_RESOURCES");
    registerEndpoints();
    configureSwagger();
}
```